# Connecting to a remote CentOS machine

Tags: centos, remote-access, remote-desktop

I am trying to connect to a remote system which has CentOS running on it from a Windows machine. I am getting the following error:

[image]

My remote computer is on and is available on the network. I tried following the steps mentioned on this website http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Remote_Access_to_the_CentOS_6_Desktop to enable remote access on centos as well.

Currently I can access the remote sever through commandline utility like Putty only.

Comment: PuTTY is the best tool to use.  You have to remember, with CentOS 6, you need to use `SSH` not `telnet`

Comment: @GoinOff I use putty for command Line access. I want to use remote desktop for GUI access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted by PaulM, I followed the steps in the website to install VNCServer on the centos machine.

To connect from my linux machine, I wrote the following commands:

vncviewer
IPAddress:5901

Adding the port number specifically made it work

Answer (score 1):

I use VNC for remote GUI admin work on CentOS device's from windows its nice and easy to set up and use, below are links to CentOS 6.5 set up guide and 7

https://www.howtoforge.com/vnc-server-installation-centos-6.5

https://www.howtoforge.com/vnc-server-installation-on-centos-7

Let me know how you get on :)

Comment: I followed the steps mentioned. I am getting the following error: ssh: connect to host port 22: No route to host
I can ping the address though.

Comment: I am getting the following error now: unable to connect to host: No route to host (113)

I opened port 5901 using the iptables command

Answer (score -2):

### CentOs to centOs Only

## No Need Any Softwares Already Centos have TigerVnc Viewer

1.Enable Remote desktop in your centos system
Goto System-->Preference-->Remote Desktop

```
             **i.Enable allow other user to view your Desktop**

             **ii.Enable allow other user to control your Desktop**

             **iii.You must confirm each access to this machine allow or cancel**

             **iv.if you ask any password to enable and type your password**
```

## Notification Area:

```
         Some one connect your system its enable to shows the icon on top panel.
```